# Mark a AWS data pipeline as succeeded via AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a lot of pipelines on AWS that use data pipeline. I wont be able to meet the May 12 deadline to move my pipelines. I am looking for alternatives to monitor my pipelines without the console. So far I have been able to find a way for all my use cases via the AWS cli.

I am only having trouble finding a way to mark a pipeline component as 'finished' via the cli. According to the [datapipeline API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/index.html) documentation, the `set-task-status` ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/set-task-status.html)) command can help you achieve this. However, the command requires a `task-id` value which is obtained via  the `PollForTask` ([link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datapipeline/poll-for-task.html)) command and I can't seem to get poll for task to work.

Is there another of updating status of your pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

The CLI command for this is `set-status`, eg:

```
aws datapipeline set-status --pipeline-id dp-xxxxx --object-ids xxxx --status FINISHED
```

The `set-task-status` command is only used when you have deployed a custom task runner that is polling for work and needs to notify DPL of a status change.